# Show: $C^1(\Omega)\subset C^{0,1}(\Omega)\subset C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)\subset C^0(\Omega)$.

Tags: analysis, holder-spaces

> > Show that
> >     $$
> > C^1(\Omega)\subset C^{0,1}(\Omega)\subset C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)\subset C^0(\Omega)~~~~~~~\forall0<\lambda\leq 1.
> > $$

Hello, I have some problems to show these inclusions! In order to get some help, I wrote down all the definitions that we had (please see below).

So consider $u\in C^1(\Omega)$. Concerning to the second definition of 1.), then $u$ is continious on the domain $\Omega$ and the first partial derivatives are continious on $\Omega$.

Now I have to show, that $u\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$.

Which definition do I have to use resp. what do I have to show?

---

*This are the definitions that we wrote down: (unfortunately rather many)*

1.) $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a domain and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$
C(\Omega):=C^0(\Omega):=\left\{u\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}|u\mbox{ continious on }\Omega\right\}
$$

$$
C^k(\Omega):=\left\{u\in C(\Omega)|\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n\mbox{ with }0\leq\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq k: D^{\alpha} u(x)\in C(\Omega)\right\}
$$

$$
C^{\infty}(\Omega):=\bigcap\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}C^k(\Omega)
$$

2.) $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ limited domain and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$
C^k(\overline{\Omega}):=\left\{u\in C^k(\Omega)|\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^{n}\mbox{ with }\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq k\mbox{ is }D^{\alpha}u\mbox{ uniformly continious on }\Omega\right\}
$$

3.) $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a (not necessarily limited)) domain and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$
C^k(\overline{\Omega}):=\left\{u\colon\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}|\forall~R>0: u\in C^k(\overline{B_R(0)\cap\Omega})\right\}
$$

4.) $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ limited domain, $\lambda\in ]0,1]$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$
C^{k,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega}):=\left\{u\in C^k(\overline{\Omega})|\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n\mbox{ with }\lvert\alpha\rvert\leq k: H_{\alpha,\lambda}(u)<\infty\right\},
$$

whereat

$$
H_{\alpha,\lambda}(u):=\sup\limits_{x,y\in\overline{\Omega}, x\neq y}\left\{\frac{\lvert D^{\alpha} u(x)-D^{\alpha} u(y)\rvert}{\lVert x-y\rVert^{\lambda}}\right\}
$$

5.) $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a (not necessarily limited) domain, $\lambda\in ]0,1]$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$

$$
C^{k,\lambda}(\Omega):=\left\{u\in C^k(\Omega)|\forall\overline{B}_R(x)\subset\Omega: u\in C^{k,\lambda}(\overline{B}_R(x))\right\}
$$

$$
C^{k,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega}):=\left\{u\colon\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}|\forall R>0: u\in C^{k,\lambda}(\overline{B_R(0)\cap\Omega})\right\}
$$

Comment: Is $\Omega$ connected or pathwise connected?

Comment: In my reading, $\Omega$ is a domain and this means in our reading: non-empty, open and connected

Comment: Does the first definition in 5.) mean, that u is continious and local lipschitz-continious? And did I get it right,that, in order to show the first  inclusion $C^0(\Omega)\subset C^{0,1}(\Omega)$ I "only" have to show that any $u\in C^1(\Omega)$ is local lipschitz-continious?

Comment: Yes @math, that's right. ALso, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I - $C^1(\Omega)\subset C^{0,1}(\Omega)$

Take any $B_R(x)$ such that $\overline{B_R(x)}\subset \Omega$. If $u\in C^1(\Omega)$ then $u\in C^1(\overline{B_R(x)})$, which implies that $\|u'(x)\|\leq C$, where $C>0$ is a constant.

Can you concude from here?

Hint: Apply Mean Value Theorem.

II - $C^{0,1}(\Omega)\subset C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$

Take any $B_R(x)$ such that $\overline{B_R(x)}\subset \Omega$ and $z,y\in \overline{B_R(x)}$. Note

\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{\|u(z)-u(y)\|}{\|z-y\|^\lambda} &=&  \frac{\|u(z)-u(y)\|}{\|z-y\|}\frac{\|z-y\|}{\|z-y\|^\lambda}      \nonumber \\
   &=& \frac{\|u(z)-u(y)\|}{\|z-y\|}\|z-y\|^{1-\lambda}\nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}

Can you conclude from here?

III - $C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)\subset C^0(\Omega)$

This is immediate from definition.

Comment: I) Consider $u\in C^1(\Omega)$, that means $u\in C(\Omega)$ and $D^1 u=\nabla u\in C(\Omega)$. Then for any $x\in\Omega$ and $\overline{B_R(x)}\subset\Omega$, it is $\nabla u\in C(\overline{B_R(x)})$. Because $\overline{B_R(x)}$ is compact, any first partial dervative is limited, which means for the euclidean norm of $\nabla u$ that $\Vert\nabla u(x)\rVert < C$ for a $C>0$. So the multidim. mean value theorem says, that there is a $z$ in the connection line between $x$ and $y$, $z\neq x, z\neq y$ so that $u(x)-u(y)=\nabla u(z)\cdot (x-y)$. From this it follows that $H_{0,1}$ is limited by C.

Comment: So $u\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$ and especially u is local lipschitz-continious because it was shown for ALL $B_R(x)$ and for lipschitz-continuty only one neighbourhood where $H_{0,1}<\infty$ is necesary. Right?

Comment: Yes @math12, that's right.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I try the other inclusions and post them here later.

Comment: You are welcome @math12. As an exercise, you could also try to prove that if $1>\lambda\geq\alpha> 0$ then $C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)\subset C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

Comment: II) One gets (using, that $H_{0,1}(u)\leq C<\infty$ for a $C>0$, because $u\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$ is assumed), that $\frac{\lvert u(z)-u(y)\rvert}{\lVert z-y\rVert^{\lambda}}\leq C\cdot R^{1-\lambda}<\infty$ for any $x\in\Omega$ any $R>0$, any $\overline{B_R(x)}\subset\Omega$ and any $y,z$ in that arbitrary $\overline{B_R(x)}$ with $y\neq z$. So the supremum over any $z,y\in\overline{B_R(x)}, y\neq z$ is $<\infty$, too. So $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$. That $u\in C(\Omega)$ resp. $u\in C(\overline{B_R(x)})$ is clear, it already follows from $u\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$. - Is this right, too?

Comment: It is right, you have to fix just a detail. It is not $R$, it is $2R$, because $\|z-y\|\leq 2R$. Note that $2R$ is the diameter of $B_R(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question: Why is the Hölder-continuity on $\Omega$ defined via the Hölder-continuity on all $\overline{B_R(x)}$ for any $x$ and any $R>0$? I mean: Is it the same to say a function is Hölder-continious on whole $\Omega$ or to say it is Hölder-continious in all $\overline{B_R(x)}$ for any $x\in\Omega$ and any $R>0$? One needs ONE constant on whole $\Omega$, or? Is it then the same to say it does have local constants for any $x\in\Omega$? Does one chhose the "biggest"local constant as the constant which is valid for whole $\Omega$?

Comment: This definition that you are using is saying that $u$ is locally Holder continuous. In general, for each ball, you can find a constant and this constant may go to infinite. Every domain can be written as the union of compact sets $K_n$ such that $K_n\subset K_{n+1}$. If your function is locally Holder continuous, then the constant $C_n$ in each $K_n$ is finite. If the sequence $C_n$ is bounded, then you can say that your function is Holder continuous in all $\Omega$, or equivalenlty, in all $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: For example, you can verify that for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, the function $x^2$ is locally Holder, however, it is not Holder continuous in the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But under "locally Holder continious" I understand that there is ONE ball around any x, in which the function is Holder continious, but here the definition says that this is FOR ALL balls around x. So to my understanding, the definition does not say that the function is locally Holder continious.

Comment: It is for every ball $B_R(x)$ such that $\overline{B_R(x)}\subset\Omega$, or equivalenly, for every open set $U$ such that $\overline{U}\subset\Omega$

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the point! A function is called locally Holder continuous if for every x in X there exists a neighborhood U of x such that f restricted to U is Holder continuous. But here the definition says for ALL neighboorhods. So the definition says not that u is locally Holder continious. But it says global Holder continious, or?

Comment: That's not the usual (correct?) definition of locally Holder continuous. The usual (correct?) definition is $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally Holder continuous (for short $u\in C_{loc}^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$ if $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{U})$ for all open $U\subset\Omega$ with $\overline{U}\subset\Omega$. Note that this definition is equivalently with that that you gave in your question.

Comment: Ok. But our script says that a function that is out of $C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ (as defined in the first post) is called Holder continuous on $\Omega$ with exponent $\lambda$. So I thought that this definition has to define GLOBAL Holder continuity. And therefore I wondered why this is done over the Holder continuity on all neighborhoods and not by just saying: a function is holder continuous on whole $\Omega$ if there is a constant for whole $\Omega$ so that...

Comment: Our script says, that a function out of $C^{0,\lambda}$ (as defined above) is called "Holder continious on $\Omega$. So I understood this definition as a definition of global Holder continuity. And therefore I wondered why global continuity is definied via the Holder continuity on all neighborhoods instead of define it by that the supremum is finite on whole $\Omega$. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Okay, then the first definition only says locally holder-continious. But one can say: A function out of the second definition, i.e. $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$ is holder continious on whole $\overline{\Omega}$, right?

Comment: I have to see this script. In the way it is written, it does not make sense to me. When one say: "A function out of the second definition", this does not mean nothing. One has to be more precise. One way more general to define Holder spaces is: Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ be "any" set. We say that $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(U)$ if $\frac{\|u(x)-u(y)\|}{\|x-y\|^\lambda}$ is bounded for all $x,y\in U$. By using thi definition, you can see that $C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)=C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$, in the sense that you extend functions or restrict functions.

Comment: Your definition 4) and 5) for $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ are equivalenlty for bounded domains. They are considering Holder space in the whole of $\Omega$.

Comment: So a function $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$ is (global) Holder-continious on $\overline{\Omega}$ (and therefore on whole $\Omega$)? And a function in $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ is only locally Holder-continious on $\Omega$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean: For a limited domain if definition 4 is fullfilled for a function 4 and $k=0,\lambda=1$ that means u Holder-continious on whole $\overline{\Omega}$ and so Holder-continious on whole $\Omega$. For an unlimited domain if the first definition of 5.) is fullfilled for a function u that means u is locally Holder-continious on $\Omega$. If u fullfills the second definition of 5.) that means u is Holder-continious on whole $\overline{\Omega}$ and therefore Holder-continious on whole $\Omega$?

Comment: For your first question, the answer is yes. For your second question, the answer is no. The second definition of 5) (for unbounded domains) is saying that your functions is Holder cotinuous for every open set $U\subset \overline{\Omega}$. This is not the same to say that the function is Holder continuous in all $\Omega$. As a example consider the function $x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This function is Holder continuous in the sense of the second definition of 5), however, there is no constant $C>0$ such that $\frac{\|u(x)-u(y)\|}{\|x-y\|^\lambda}\leq C$

Comment: Note that in my last comment, there is a difference: intead of considereing $U\subset \Omega$ with $\overline{U}\subset\Omega$, we consider $U\subset \overline{\Omega}$. THe idea is that the second definition of 5) is also considering values up to the boundary of $\Omega$, while the first consider values onlye in the interior of $\Omega$. Another example is the function $\sqrt{x}$ in $[0,1]$. This function belongs to $C^{0,1}((0,1))$, but it does not beling ti $C^{0,1}([0,1])$.

Comment: One last try. I. bounded domain $\Omega$: then $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$ means: $u$ Holder-continious on whole $\overline{\Omega}$ and so $u$ Holder-continious on whole $\Omega$. And $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ means that $u$ only locally Holder-continious on $\Omega$. II. unbounded domain $\Omega$: Then $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ means only locally Holder-continious on $\Omega$ and $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$ means that $u$ \locally Holder-continious on $\overline{\Omega}$. - Now right?

Comment: Yes @math12, that's the idea. I also suggest you drawn some examples. Find example of functions $u$ such that (in both cases, bounded and unbounded) $u\in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ but $u\notin C^{0,\lambda}(\overline{\Omega})$.